# Kill thread without access to the thread object

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread, and I would like to let the user kill that thread when they click on the progress notification.

My notification works fine, but in my BroadcastReciever I can't manage to kill the thread.

I can't use `thread.interupt()`, because I don't have access to the thread object. This also means I can't use a public boolean to terminate the thread.

I also tried passing the process id as an extra, and killing it using `Process.killProcess(pid)`, but this has the rather unfortunate side effect of killing my UI thread and any other threads I might have running.

Finally, I tried using the thread id, but the documentation doesn't mention using this for killing the thread.

In short, how can I kill my thread using the primitive data types that can be passed as extras?

Comment: A thread is running inside a process, your whole application is running on probably one process, all threads created are running inside the app process, that's why killing processes doesn't work. Why don't you have access to the thread object? You can always create a static class with static fields to store the tread object in while you're creating the tread, this class should make it easy to access the thread object anywhere you want. I'm sorry but I don't know how to kill threads without their instances, but I would like to find a solution using the thread objects if that's possible.

Comment: @TimVisee - I'll give a static list a shot - If my application is destroyed will the thread also be destoryed? - I am worried that I might run into a situation where the reference to the thread will be destoryed and I can't kill the thread

Comment: I actually don't know exactly, I've never coded an Android application sadly, so yeah I can't give you an answer on this one. I assume though that the thread will be destroyed, it will be destroyed for sure if you kill the application process. Killing the application thread (not the other thread) shouldn't kill the other thread, you can always give it a try of course! You might need to use the main thread as a master for the other thread, you need to keep the main thread running to be able to reach the thread instance as far as I know. [1/3]

Comment: You can always create another thread to run your application in, which is managed by the master thread. So you can kill the application thread while you keep the master thread running to ensure you've the ability to destroy the other thread later on, which is still controlled by the master thread. This might be very confusing, at least I find it difficult to explain haha. What I'm basically saying is that you might need to run your application in a new thread which is mastered by the main thread. [2/3]

Comment: If you'd like to kill the application you only need to kill the application thread, this ensures you'll have control over other threads you might create using the master thread. Anyways, feel free to ask me a question if you have trouble understanding the above! [3/3]

Comment: hi @TimVisee as I saw you mention that you never coded in Android before; this "You can always create another thread to run your application in, which is managed by the master thread." is not very relevant. In Android the UI is always rendered by the UI thread, and that is always managed by the framework. You simply have a bunch of callbacks being called by the framework in the UI thread to create your views.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the notice. I'll probably leave this question to the Android geeks for now!

Comment: @jcw if the application object is destroyed, that means that the Process running your application is destroyed and everything in the app is gone. Including any Thread you might have started. But if you're using a Service to execute a background task (that's what I understood from your question), there's no reason your Application will be killed as the system will try to the best of it capability, to honor your service execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at it with the wrong approach.

If you have a thread running and a notification on the notification bar I'll assume that you have a service running, and this service know the thread and does have a reference to it. That way, the PendinIntent for your notification, should not simply trigger a BroadcastReceiver, but trigger the same Service with an Intent extra indicating that the service should cancel the thread.

so assuming your service:

```
public MyService extend Service{

   private Runnable myThread = new Runnable{
     @Override
     public void run(){
       // ... here you're doing the job on the different thread
     }
   };
}
```

something like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i.putExtra("cancel", true);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(// put here the intent)
```

then, whenever the notification is clicked, your service that have the thread will be executed from `onStartCommand` and all you need to do is:

```
cancel = getIntent.getBooleanExtra("cancel", false);
```

then inside the thread you must check for the `boolean cancel` from the service like this:

```
public MyService extend Service{

   boolean cancel = false;

   private Runnable myThread = new Runnable{
     @Override
     public void run(){
        // ... here you're doing the job on the different thread

      if(cancel)
         return;
     }
   };
}
```

Comment: My thread isn't running from a service right now, but that looks like the right way to go. I'll see how that goes

Comment: Absolutely yes. If it's something that should keep running even after the activity is destroyed, put it in a service.

Comment: This worked - it just took a little bit of playing around with (because  I can have multiple threads running at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is stopping it from the inside. That means that you define inside a controller (for example, a `boolean`) that checks some additional event within your app that determines if your `Thread` has to still execute or not. This implies that you'll have to put your code within a loop with a `Thead.sleep()` object inside to not overkill your thread, or use a `Handler` inside with a `postDelay()` action inside, but that's the way.

If you don't want to use it, you can also declare a `BroadcastReceiver` inside. You register your receiver, and wait for some action you define (I recommend an own action so you don't interfere with Android's) and once your receive event fires, just use `return` in your `Thread` so it exits.